# React JS - Reset Form Data after Modal Close

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

I'm trying to reset my form data when a modal closes. I think part of my problem is that the form data `<Mint>` is in another component.

Honestly, any time the modal is shown or hidden I would like to reset the data.
So if there is a way I can reset the form data inside the `toggleModalOne()` function that would be awesome, but I can't figure out how.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
// BuyIt.jsx

import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextLoop from "react-text-loop";
import Modal from "react-modal";
import Mint from "../../components/slider/mint.js";

const BuyIt = () => {
   const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  function toggleModalOne() {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  }

  return (
     <div className="div-buyNowBtn">            
            <button id="buyNowBtn" className="white-fill-bg btn-outline btn-lg" onClick={toggleModalOne}>
              Buy Now
            </button>
          </div>
      
     <Modal
         isOpen={isOpen}
         onRequestClose={toggleModalOne}
         contentLabel="My dialog"
         className="custom-modal"
         overlayClassName="custom-overlay"
         closeTimeoutMS={500}
      >
         <Mint/>
      </Modal>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You could wrap your Modal around a check to see if isOpen is true. This will make the whole modal re-render each time rather than just hiding and showing it but it still being in the DOM (which is what I am assuming is happening).

```js
{ isOpen && 
     <Modal
         isOpen={isOpen}
         onRequestClose={toggleModalOne}
         contentLabel="My dialog"
         className="custom-modal"
         overlayClassName="custom-overlay"
         closeTimeoutMS={500}
      >
         <Mint></Mint>
      </Modal>
}
```

Comment: This is genius! I love it and it works great

Comment: In my case, I do not pass data to components inside Modal but fetch data from the inner components. This also works for my case!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a parent function to reset a child's form state, you probably will want to lift the state up to the parent and pass it down as a prop.